# Change messages/texts at runtime (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

In an innosetup script it is possible to define messages like this:

```
[Messages]
WelcomeLabel2=This wizard will update [name] to version [name/ver]
```

Now I would like to change this message at runtime, like this:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    //this doesn't work        
    WelcomeLabel2=NEW MESSAGE 
end;
```

What is the correct way to do this? I want to dynamically change the contents of the welcome page to display whether the setup is performing a new installation or update. Based on the existence of some executables in the installation directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way;

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[CustomMessages]
en.WelcomeLabel2_ForInstall=intstall {#SetupSetting("AppName")}, {#SetupSetting("AppVersion")}
en.WelcomeLabel2_ForUpdate=update {#SetupSetting("AppName")} to {#SetupSetting("AppVersion")}

[code]
procedure InitializeWizard(); 
var
  message: string;
begin 
    //some logic
    message := 'WelcomeLabel2_ForUpdate';
    WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption := CustomMessage(message);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  case CurPageID of
      wpFinished : WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Caption := 'bla bla';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I would like to do this too with WizardForm.FinishedLabelNoIcons.Caption, but the Inno Setup compiler errors with "Unknown identifier".

Comment: Updated above, seems you can get at that via `WizardForm.FinishedLabel` (but not in `InitializeWizard`)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have to change so many messages that it might be a better idea to dynamically change the MessagesFile in the code section. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can, they are compiled into the setup and used automatically based on language

Answer (score 0):

Hm, this won't work, I think. One way could be to create two pages for the installer - one with the layout for the installation process and one with the layout for the update process. Then, change the page sequence in a way that you manually decide which one to show.

An example for integrating a new page into the process can be found in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212007/inno-setup-add-a-custom-input-field/3212062#3212062).

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new page based on the welcome page? Or would I have to recreate the welcome page?

Comment: Event though Alex K.'s solution is correct: I don't think there's something like "page inheritance" - you'd have to create the pages from scratch.